# Issue with Android Library with Proguard

Tags: android, proguard

I am working on an android library project, compiled it without ProGuard.

When I use that library in a project, I get no error, build is successful.

But when the library is compiled using ProGuard, and after using it on a project, I'm getting an error while trying to build the project.

> Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS:   -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=gasp
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a load for Lcom/yuwee/sdk/YuWeeCallActivity; to set up parameter 0 for com/yuwee/sdk/YuWeeCallActivity$$Lambda$4 but got -1
>       at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:756)
>       at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring$InvokedynamicRewriter.attemptAllocationBeforeArgumentLoads(LambdaDesugaring.java:543)
>       at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring$InvokedynamicRewriter.visitInvokeDynamicInsn(LambdaDesugaring.java:427)
>       at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:1623)
>       at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1126)
>       at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:698)
>       at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
>       at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:477)
>       at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:361)
>       at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:314)
>       at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:711)

:app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments {--input /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/43.jar --output /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/13.jar --input /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/0.jar --output /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/1.jar --input /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/41.jar --output /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/11.jar --input /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/54.jar --output /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/24.jar --input /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/32.jar --output /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/2.jar --input /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/44.jar --output /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/14.jar --input /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/48.jar --output /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/18.jar --input /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/34.jar --output /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/4.jar --input /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/49.jar --output /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/19.jar --classpath_entry /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug --classpath_entry /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/0.jar --classpath_entry /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/32.jar --classpath_entry /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/33.jar --classpath_entry /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/34.jar --classpath_entry /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/35.jar --classpath_entry /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/36.jar --classpath_entry /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/37.jar --classpath_entry /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/38.jar --classpath_entry /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/39.jar --classpath_entry /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/40.jar --classpath_entry /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/41.jar --classpath_entry /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/42.jar --classpath_entry /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/43.jar --classpath_entry /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/44.jar --classpath_entry /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/45.jar --classpath_entry /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/46.jar --classpath_entry /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/47.jar --classpath_entry /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/48.jar --classpath_entry /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/49.jar --classpath_entry /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/50.jar --classpath_entry /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/51.jar --classpath_entry /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/52.jar --classpath_entry /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/53.jar --classpath_entry /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/54.jar --classpath_entry /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/55.jar --classpath_entry /media/tanay/New Volume/Projects/Office/TestYuWeeDepen/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/56.jar --bootclasspath_entry /home/tanay/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar --bootclasspath_entry /home/tanay/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-27/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar --bootclasspath_entry /home/tanay/Android/android-studio/jre/jre/lib/resources.jar --bootclasspath_entry /home/tanay/Android/android-studio/jre/jre/lib/rt.jar --bootclasspath_entry /home/tanay/Android/android-studio/jre/jre/lib/jsse.jar --bootclasspath_entry /home/tanay/Android/android-studio/jre/jre/lib/jce.jar --bootclasspath_entry /home/tanay/Android/android-studio/jre/jre/lib/charsets.jar --min_sdk_version 16 --desugar_try_with_resources_if_needed --desugar_try_with_resources_omit_runtime_classes --legacy_jacoco_fix}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved after removing Java 1.8 Support from a library project's build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

add `-ignorewarnings` in the end of proguard-rules.pro file which you can find under Gradle Scripts